# Why doesn't my calculator calculate the answer?

Tags: python, user-interface, syntax-error, calculator

```
def Functional_Output(Validate_Input):
    try:
        while '(' in Validate_Input and ')' in Validate_Input:
            Validate_Output = Validate_Input.count('(')

            Intake_Input = Validate_Input.find('(')
            fin = Validate_Input.find(')')+1

            while Validate_Output > 1:
                Intake_Input = Validate_Input.find('(', Intake_Input+1)
                Validate_Output -= 1

            receive_value = Validate_Input[Intake_Input:fin]
            receive_input = calcula(receive_value.replace('(', ''). replace(')', ''))
            Validate_Input = Validate_Input.replace(recieve_value, recieve_input)

        DisplayAnswer = float(AddFunction(Validate_Input))

    except:
        DisplayAnswer = "Error"
    return DisplayAnswer
def AddFunction(Validate_Input):
    add_selection = Validate_Input.split()

    while len(add_selection) != 1:

        for index in range(len(add_selection)):
            if add_selection[index] == '/':
                add_selection[index] = str(float(add_selection[index-1]) / float(add_selection[index+1]))
                add_selection.pop(index+1)
                add_selection.pop(index-1)
                break
            elif add_selection[index] == '*':
                add_selection[index] = str(float(add_selection[index-1]) * float(add_selection[index+1]))
                add_selection.pop(index+1)
                add_selection.pop(index-1)
                break
        if not '/' in add_selection and not '*' in add_selection:
            while len(add_selection) !=1:
                for index in range(len(add_selection)):
                    add_selection[index] = str(float(add_selection[index]) + float(add_selection[index+1]))

                    add_selection.pop(index+1)
                    break
    return add_selection[0]

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("Calculator")
txtDisplay =tkinter.StringVar()
operator = ""
App_Function = Calculator_App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

How come when I click on the button '9' then '+' then '1' the entry returns the message 'Error' instead of '10'! Why is this?
Could it be something to do with the addFunction function and the indexing?

Comment: Please don't code-dump, try to isolate the part where your code seems to be doing something that is not intended.

Comment: Why surely this would mean you could run the program and see for yourself? I'm just trying to help!

Comment: This is almost certainly not the cause of your error, but just a suggestion: the most common Python style is to use `lower_case_names_with_underscores` for modules, functions and variables, and use `CapitolizedNamesWithoutUnderscores` for classes. Following this convention will make it easier for other people to read your code. Not all standard library modules follow this guideline (which is documented, along with lots of other style suggestions in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but it is recommended for new code.

Comment: Ok I edited some code away. Anyone help?

Comment: Since you are new to SO you should read some of the guidelines in the Help Center, in your case this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.`

Comment: That's better. First I would drop the `except:` to something more specic, that way you can trackdown which part of the code is raising the error.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry next time I will - but why is it such a big deal? I just need some simple help! Where has humanity gone?!

Comment: Some debugging advise: Get rid of your `try`/`except` blocks. Let the exception you're running into break the program at the very point the error is happening. It will give you a traceback you can use to find out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I literally have no idea where to start

Comment: Start by removing the `try/except` block, it will raise a error(TypeError,ValueError...) on a line, then you go to this line and see what it is, and what it should be.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Deb/Downloads/ty.py", line 78, in Answer_Output
    DisplayAnswer = Functional_Output(operator)
  File "C:/Users/Deb/Downloads/ty.py", line 98, in Functional_Output
    DisplayAnswer = float(AddFunction(Validate_Input))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '8+9'

Comment: It seems that you are trying to add a string and them convert it to a float

Comment: How would I fix it then?

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
line 98, in Functional_Output DisplayAnswer = float(AddFunction(Validate_Input))
```

AddFunction is returning a string: '8+9';
Then you are trying to convert this string to a float.
It trows a ValueError, cuz strings can't be turned to floats.

To fix this you need to go to you AddFunction and make that it returns 8+9 instead of '8+9',

I think your problem is in this line:

```
add_selection[index] = str(float(add_selection[index]) + float(add_selection[index+1]))
```

You are converting add_selection[index] to a float, then to a string. try removing the outer str()

EDIT:

The only way to know further is to print check this line:

Try doing this:

```
print add_selection[index], add_selection[index+1]
print type(add_selection[index]),type(add_selection[index+1])
```

EDIT2:

Looking better at your code there's two things that might fix you program.

**1) The easy hack**

In `AddFunction` change:

```
return add_selection[0]
```

to

```
return eval(add_selection[0])
```

Since the AddFunction is returning a `'9+1' <type str>`, using eval will evaluate this to `10 <type int>`. Actually you could remove the whole `AddFunction` and just use `DisplayAnswer = float(eval(Validate_Input))`. But note that this is a [dirty trick and a hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#Security_risks).

**2) Rewrite**

I note that you are using each button in the `add_Components` both the display information(a string) but also as the value for when pressing each button, thus concatenating operator with the new value. `operator += self.value`.

But mostly the problem is that you are dealing with strings instead of integers, when you set the value of the button to be `'1'` it's not the same as setting it to be `1`, you should change your program to be using the proper type for the values, numbers being integers, strings for the operators. Then you will have to rewrite how your `AddFunction` to work with both.

And lastly you `operator` being a global variable is really frowned upon, and can lead to several problems further on.

Comment: Nope same error came up. I agree with you on that it is that line which is causing the error

Comment: print check that line.

Comment: I don't know where I could place that line